# Exporting a Path Variable inside a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

I have created a script to download Terraform onto my server and install it.

```
#!/bin/bash

wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.7.0/terraform_0.7.0_linux_amd64.zip

unzip terraform_0.7.0_linux_amd64.zip

echo "export PATH=$PATH:/root/terraform_dir" >> /root/.bash_profile

source /root/.bash_profile

terraform --version
```

This code is working perfectly. But once the script is completed and comes out, the `.bash_profile` file is back at its original state. i.e the path variable is not updated.

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
```

when I give `terraform --version` outside the shell script it is not working fine.

But when I give `su -` , and then try `terraform --version` it is actually working fine.

Is there any work around for it or automated script for it to the update the `.bash_profile`. I don't want to restart my session every time I update the `.bash_profile`?

Comment: Are you saying that it's not working when you're not root but it is when you are root? Because that's pretty evident by the profile you edited.

Comment: In which environment you start your script? Is it root-only? Not in a cron-job? Do you start it as a regular user? Remember that bei `>>` you always append the export line into the file.

Comment: Not working when i'm logged in as a root user only. 
No it is not a cron job.
This script will always be run as a root user only.

Comment: Assume that there are no other users logged in the server or we have to create one after running the script only. So it will be ran using root and root only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shell scripts run in a subshell (which you define int the first line as #!/bin/bash), any change in the environment is local to that subshell, so, the sourcing of bash_profile affects only the subshell.

To execute the commands in your current shell, use the source command to run the script in your current shell  (http://ss64.com/bash/source.html)

e.g.
instead of

```
$ ./myscript.sh
```

run:

```
$ source ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: Thanks a ton man! This worked!

Comment: Happy to help. If this has helped you, please accept the answer :)

Comment: Is there no solution to accomplish this within a startup script? I'd like to modify the PATH fully automatically on boot just from a startup script. (Preferably without modifying profile or anything like that)

Comment: I guess you can export the path variable for that particular session, without editing the profile.